# How to call a non-static method in a java program without getting any null value in the object?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have one java program. In that, I have included one jar file which contains the method that I need to call to get the needed output.

I have included jar's package name with class name. My code is,

```
import com.plug.abc;
public class xyz
{
private abc object;
//lines to initiate logs
if(object==null)
//prints Object is null
else
object.method();
}
```

Now, object created is always null so that the method cannot be executed. If I remove the null check in the object and directly called method, I am getting Null pointer exception.

Is there any mistake in my above code or in the included jar file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the above code is no valid java code as far as I can tell, there are if just dangling on class level, no method anywhere and it is unclear what you are actually asking for.

Comment: Is your if/else in a method or constructor?

Comment: Please post the important parts of the code (i.e. a bit more than this). Post the method in which you create `object` by [edit]ing your post.

Comment: Please include an actual "working" example of your code, not just some not working pseudo code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are looking for a valid code snippet.

Your attempt is not a valid code for sure as it will not be compiled by Java compiler. You can access logical blocks from Java behaviours (methods) block only.

For ex-

```
import com.plug.abc;
public class xyz
{
private abc object;
//lines to initiate logs
if(object==null)
//prints Object is null
else
object.method();
}
```

should be refactored to

```
import com.plug.abc;
public class xyz
{
    private abc object;
    public void callNonStatic() {
        //lines to initiate logs
        if(object==null)
            //prints Object is null, assuming object is created as part of constructor or any other method
        else
            object.nonStaticMethod();
    }
    public void callStatic() {
        //an optional way and not encouraged
        if(object==null)
            //prints Object is null, assuming object is created as part of constructor or any other method
        else
            // this will work with compile time warning
            object.staticMethod();

        // Ideal way of calling a static method
        abc.staticMethod();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are never creating the object, you need something like:

```
private abc object = new abc();
```

If it is static method, you call

```
abc.method()
```

directly